# Will SDL discontinue Smart Target in future as Fredhopper is sold out by SDL?

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper

Recently, we have learned that SDL sold Fredhopper. It means SDL will discontinue the SmartTarget product?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, even though Fredhopper is sold by SDL, SDL SmartTarget continues to rely on Fredhopper as the indexing/querying engine, no matter the owner. To be more precise, this is true for 2013, Web 8, Web 8.5. With Tridion Sites 9, there will be a different indexing/querying engine in use. But that does not affect Smarttarget, or rather Experience Optimization (XO) as it's called starting from Web 8 onward.

Comment: Thanks Atila, Do we know what will be used for indexing/querying in Sites 9?

Comment: Don't know whether it's public information yet so I'd rather not disclose it at the moment, but that info will be available by the end of August. I will update my answer at that point.

Comment: It’s not a secret that it’s Elasticsearch. See: https://youtu.be/2gcBd0p-_u0

Comment: https://youtu.be/2gcBd0p-_u0?t=20m2s more precisely and get the dulcet tones of Rai telling you just why it's a great idea!!